# how to add a new image to FullScreenActivity.java

Tags: android

when looking at the Graphical layout everything looks great. But when i deploy it to my device, the plank image goes missing from the right side.

how would i fix this?

Here is my XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/grid"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

    <!--
         The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc.
    -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/blue" 
        android:layout_gravity="top" />



</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you add some screen shots?

Comment: i fixed it. for some reason it required me to change the dip value of the second image before it would display it. I guess it can't be the same as the image above it... even though they are oriented differently. weird...